# How can I disable error logging in console for a Dojo's JsonRest query?

Tags: javascript, dojo

My project uses a JsonRest store to access it's data. It'l all working fine. The problem is that when the server returns an error, even if the correct part of the code is called, and the functionality works as it should, the object logs an ugly error to the console.

My code:

```
function loadData() {
    self.storeItem.query({
        'id_metric' : self.selectMetrics.value,
        'id_client' : self.selectClients.value
    }).then(
        (res) => populateResults(res),
        ()=>{
            // this is called correctly...
            query('.res').forEach(domConstruct.destroy);
            domConstruct.place('<tr class="sem res"><td>No results</td></tr>', "tableLines", 'first');
        }
    );
}
```

.

```
// ..but this is logged in console:
Object { message: "Unable to load http://localhost:300…", stack: ".cache["dojo/errors/create"]/</</_3…", response: Object, status: 404, responseText: "{"errors":["Not found…", 
xhr: XMLHttpRequest }
```

How can I make the store not show the error ?

I know I could change server behavior to return a code 200 result instead of 404. But what I want is just to make it not send the error to the console.

Comment: Could you please post your code full code for JsonRest?

Comment: PS: May I ask you... from your snippet I see you are using arrow function ES6 syntax on your code.... do you have any issues when building the app using dojo build tools?

Comment: I still don't use Dojo build tools. Still newbie at it. Sorry.

Comment: Just for curiosity I have tested a dojo app which use some ES6 syntax likearrow function => unfortunately with normal configurations it break the dojo build. I hope could be useful for others on SO.

Comment: @GibboK the full code for JsonRest ? you mean the instantiation ?

Comment: Anywhere in the app where you use ES6 syntax example arrow functions as ()=>{}

Comment: In one of my pages I have a method that mounts a select based on a memory store. The array passed in the instatiation of the memory store is created like this: `var data = []; res.forEach((item) => data.push({id: item['id_categoria'], label: item['nome']}));` Is this helpful ? If not create a question and mark me in a comment so I can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is logged by dojo/_base/xhr, which is used internally by dojo/store/JsonRest. I don't see a clean way to suppress it, unless you are prepared to implement your own store. If you are this is what you can do:

[dojo/_base/xhr](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojo/_base/xhr) has a failOk argument that does exactly what you want but dojo/store/JsonRest doesn't use it and the default is false (log the error to the console). So you can copy the source of JsonRest and add `failOk: true` in all xhr calls. For example in the query function:

```
    var results = xhr("GET", {
        url: this.target + (query || ""),
        handleAs: "json",
        headers: headers,
        failOk: true
    });
```

You will still be able to handle the error in your error handler function.

Comment: That may be a way. I don't think a small change in Dojo code would impact much. But I think we have different versions of Dojo installed. dojo/_base/xhr has this content on my project: https://pastebin.com/yXX85igv And I couldn't find the place where I would put this option. I tried in this line: `dojo.xhrGet({url:url, sync:true, load:function(text){`. But it didn't work. How could I make this in this version ?

Comment: The change is for `dojo/store/JsonRest` and not for `dojo/_base/xhr`. The version that you posted also has the `failOk` option. Also it is much cleaner if you make your own store (with declare) instead of changing the dojo source code.

Comment: I copied JsonRest code to a lib folder. Altered the class name to JsonRestNoError, and used that class instead. Worked fine. Thanks.